# Windows up one directory from current path

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have been searching for hours but cant find a solution to this as yet. Apologies it is probably really simple.

My program is using `CreateDirectory` to create a new directory and then set the path to it to receive a number of data files:

```
if (CreateDirectory(dateTime.c_str(), NULL) || ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS == GetLastError())
{
    SetCurrentDirectory(dateTime.c_str());
}
```

Once all the data files have been generated I would like to move back up one directory without specifying the absolute path. Something equivalent to `cd..` or `../` Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: What about calling https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx before?

Comment: Did you already tried `SetCurrentDirectory((dateTime + "\\..").c_str());`?

Comment: Your mistake is probably your reliance on relative paths. Why aren't you using absolute paths?

Comment: Thank you harper - yes GetCurrentDirectory worked with the answer below.

Comment: Absolute paths would definitely be simpler - at the time I thought I needed to use relative but Ive also found a way to use absolute paths so thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to get the current directory ([`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx)) before changing to a new one and once complete, then change back the desired directory; akin to a push/pop.

In the sample I've left out error checking and buffer size requirements for simplicity.

```
TCHAR resetDir[1024] = {};
GetCurrentDirectory(1024, resetDir);
//... Do some work, change directories etc...
// Reset the directory
SetCurrentDirectory(resetDir);
```

*Side note: the current directory when the process is launched is not necessarily the same as the directory the process image is in (the exe path).*

Relative changes can be done with a simple

```
SetCurrentDirectory(_T(".."));
```

Although basing the relative from the current directory would also work (and may be preferable);

```
SetCurrentDirectory((currentDir + _T("\\..")).c_str());
```

Comment: The current directory is managed per process. Any thread can change it at any time. Relying on the current working directory is always a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: This approach worked for me but yes I understand how it could eventuate in a bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, `cd` command ends using `SetCurrentDirectory`. So to get something equivalent to `cd..` or `cd ../` you can simply use:

```
cr = ::SetCurrentDirectory("..");
```

`cr` should be non zero if it succeded and 0 if it failed. In the latter case use `GetLastError` to get further information.